# iOS Vision detect light on binarized image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, core-image, ios11, coreml

I stuck with some issue. How can I define the light spot on the binarized image.  I am using ios11 and Vision now.

I use binarization filter `CIColorControls` (also tried to combine this with `CIColorInvert`).
For light detection, I use `VNImageRequestHandler` with `VNDetectRectanglesRequest`.
In `VNDetectRectanglesRequest` I check for `VNDetectedObjectObservation`
But can't achieve the 100% frame detection (sometimes app can't recognize light spot on frames). What I am doing wrong? Appreciate any help

Here is my code

```
 lazy var rectanglesRequest: VNDetectRectanglesRequest = {
        return VNDetectRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleRectangles)
    }()

 func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
            connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            guard let uiImage = imageFromSampleBuffer(sampleBuffer: sampleBuffer) else { return }

            let correctedImage = uiImage
                .applyingFilter("CIColorControls", withInputParameters: [
                    kCIInputSaturationKey: 0,
                    kCIInputContrastKey: 4.5,
                    kCIInputBrightnessKey: -1.54
                    ])
                //.applyingFilter("CIColorInvert", withInputParameters: nil)
              self.searchLightSpot(ciImage: correctedImage)

            DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in //unowned
                self.frameImageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: correctedImage)
            }
        }

 func searchLightSpot(ciImage: CIImage) {
        var requestOptions: [VNImageOption: Any] = [:]
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, options: requestOptions)
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
            do {
                try handler.perform([self.rectanglesRequest])
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

func handleRectangles(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        guard let observations = request.results as? [VNDetectedObjectObservation]
            else {
                print("unexpected result type from VNDetectedObjectObservation")
                return
        }
        guard let detectedObject = observations.first else {
                print("not detected object")
            return
        }

        print("detected object: ", detectedObject)
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After making additional research I understood that it looks like Apple make additional optimizations with frames

For example if we get light in the 1st frame and the next 5 frames would be the same 
It will show us the same frame so instead 5 frames - we have only 1
It means that we can not relay on static number of frames in second with 100% sure

So I can't detect the signal duration and so on....

One of the possible solution can be:

**1. We can start our timer which will get the current frame from camera (for example each 100ms)**

**2. Then we will check if the frame has white dot. Based on these results of histogramm**
 [image]

y - color (0/1 displays if white color exists on frame)

x - timeline (ms)

**3. So the output of this diagram  could be**

```
[01111100001111…]
```

**4. Then we can analyze and detect signal**

You can use [EasyImagy](https://github.com/koher/EasyImagy) 
and write your own extension to binarize and detect white spots

```
  extension Image  where Pixel == RGBA {

        fileprivate func getPixelCount() -> Int {
            return Int(10 * width / 100)
        }

        func binarize() -> (isWhite: Bool, binarizedImage: Image<RGBA>) {

            var kWidth = 0
            var img = self
            let pixelCount = getPixelCount()
            for x in 0..<width{
                var kHeight = 0
                for y in 0..<height {

                    if let _pixel = pixel(x, y) {
                        if _pixel.gray < 245 {
                            img[x, y] = .black
                            kHeight = 0
                        } else {
                            img[x, y] = .white
                            kHeight += 1
                        }

                        if kHeight > pixelCount {
                            kWidth += 1
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
                print("Hwhite: \(kHeight) Wwhite: \(kWidth)")
                if kHeight >= pixelCount && kWidth >= pixelCount  {
                    return (true, img)
                }
            }
            return (false, img)
        }
    }
```